# How i can stretch comboBox in DockPanel

Tags: wpf, xaml, statusbar, dockpanel

I want to create a status bar with combobox, progress bar and two buttons. At the left it must be progressbar, in the center combobox, that get all available free space and two buttons at the right But I get very little combobox, and dockpanel don't fill status bar..

My Xaml code

```
<StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <DockPanel Width="1004" Height="Auto" LastChildFill="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ProgressBar Name="ExecutionProgress" Height="Auto" Margin="3" MinWidth="200" MaxWidth="400" DockPanel.Dock="Left"></ProgressBar>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="Auto" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
                <Button Name="SaveExecutionLog" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Content="Save Log" Margin="2" Padding="4"></Button>
                <Button Name="ClearExecutionLog" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Content="Clear Log" Margin="2" Padding="4"></Button>
            </StackPanel>
            <ComboBox Name="ExecutionEvents" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Margin="3">
                <ComboBoxItem>jfjfjxdfvbdfhfghfghfghfghfghjfg[pjkhlp'fghfg]ophkfg]pkh]pfg]hkfg]pkh]pfghokfg]pkh]-fg</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
        </DockPanel>
</StatusBar>
```

Where is my mistake? Thank you!

Comment: Width & Height = Auto ? Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: I have just copied your code into a blank project and it works fine.

Comment: I've tested works Well ... :)

Comment: it's strange, in my project i saw very small combobox, when it was empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where was the problem, but i fixed it by changing DockPanel to Grid. It was a magic.